# onclick attribute vs eventListeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm re-writing the code of a website I created a few years ago, and I was wondering what was the most efficient way to handle the click event on an element?

I have a list of items with links to edit them, and they're all written with the `onclick="..."` HTML attribute. Is it better that way or I should use `$.bind()` or `addEventListener` to handle it? What's the best practice?

Comment: May I suggest instead of bind function, the 'on' function with delegate option? $('#fatherUl').on('click', 'li', function(){}), this avoids attaching all list items the same listener, and you attach it just to the father. (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered best practice to utilize what is called [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  What this means is you separate the layout of your HTML from the behavior of the elements.  So instead of using the onclick attribute, which mixes up element structure and behaviour, you layout your DOM structure in markup and then attached event handlers via javascript.

What this means is that is considered best practice to use javascript to attached event handlers, as follows:

```
<html>
   <script>
        ... bind event handlers to your DOM and set behaviours here
   </script>
   <body>
       .... layout your DOM here
    </body>
<html>
```

This has advantages for long-term code maintainability and extensibility.  This approach works very nicely with javascript libraries such as jQuery.

In terms of performance, you may be able to achieve performance gains via an unobtrusive javascript approach by using an intelligent caching strategy.

For more information on unobtrusive javascript, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was exactly what I was looking for. I know this is in most case a preference matter only, but this answer and the reference wiki article is really good at seeing the benefits it can bring.

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` or it's jQuery version `on` \ `bind` is the best practice as it separates the visual part-HTML from the functional part- javascript.

*Separates of concerns*.

If the code is written already, I wouldn't change it, it's not that important.

Comment: Do you know, are there any performance differences between the two methods? Event listeners from external JS files seems the best for programming and maintenance, but I wonder if it makes a difference for the end user.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby, Those kind of micro-optimizations don't bother me at all. Never encountered a problem because of those stuff, because four nested loops, yes...

Comment: That was my thought as well. Perhaps on a very large site the little improvements would make a noticeable difference, but not for the majority of uses.

Comment: Probably large websites like Facebook, but from what I read here and in the article Joe Alfano cited, these gains are minimal in most cases and it all comes down to a question of good practices for long-term code maintainability and extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

Many people will discourage the use of `onclick` because "what if you want to add another onclick event?" - personally I have never had this issue, but I can sort of understand.

If you're not using the links for anything other than a single `click` event, then `onclick` is perfectly fine. However, if you want it to be bulletproof, you probably want `addEventListener`. I actually have my own `addEvent`/`fireEvent`/`removeEvent` trio of functions that keep track of events and handle browser inconsistencies for me (bringing in `window.event`, for instance) and this works quite well.